# Creating a vector of a struct in a c++ windows form

Tags: winforms, vector, struct, c++-cli

I am trying to write a program that uses a global vector of a struct in a c++ windows form. Below is the code. The commented areas are attempts I've made to create a vector. Most of them do not compile. Some of them compile, but the program will not display. I do not understand the nature of this error because I was able to create vectors of structs in command line programs. Any help would be appreciated!

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <cliext/vector>

namespace student_database {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

/// <summary>
/// Summary for Form11
/// </summary>
public ref class Form11 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    Form11(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
    }

protected:
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    ~Form11()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }

private:

    ref struct student{
    int index;
    String^ name;
    cliext::vector <String^> essays;
    };

cliext::vector <student^> student_vector; // builds without errors, but program does not start


    // array <student^>^ Qarray;

        // static cliext::vector<student^>::generic_container^ student_vector = gcnew cliext::vector<student^>;//(0);


        // cliext::vector<student^> ^c;
         // c = gcnew(cliext::vector<student^>);


        //cliext::vector <student> student_vector = gcnew cliext::vector <student>;
         //cliext::vector<student^> ^student_vector =  gcnew(cliext::vector<student^>);
        // cliext::vector <student^>^ student_vector;
        // Microsoft::VisualC::StlClr::Ivector<student^> ^student_vector;
        // Ivector<student^> ^student_vector;



    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // Form11
        // 
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(284, 262);
        this->Name = L"Form11";
        this->Text = L"Form11";
        this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form11::Form11_Load);
        this->ResumeLayout(false);

    }
#pragma endregion
private: System::Void Form11_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         }
};
```

}

Comment: This is going to die with a TypeLoadException.  You must implement the Rule Of Three when you use STL containers.  Using C++/STL is a mistake, use `List<student^>` instead.

Comment: How would the syntax for that go? List<student^> variable; does not work. Thanks!

Comment: List is a reference type, just like student.  So you declare it as `List<student^>^ students.  Mind the hat^