# c++ winforms and standard library containers

Tags: c++, winforms, stl, containers, stdvector

I'm looking for container to use with winforms project.
I was using `std::vector` at first, but after a [little search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419715/creating-a-vector-of-a-struct-in-a-c-windows-form) I found out that using of STL in winforms project is mistake.
I can't find any documentary about any c++ winforms containers, so I need a solution.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: I'll answer each and every question you may ever have if you promise to tell me the secret to making a Windows Forms project using C++.

Comment: @IInspectable: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI -- Not technically C++, but this is most likely what the OP is using.

Comment: Also take a look here [Managed Extensions for C++ Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa712574%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). Lookup `System::List` for an appropriate container.

Comment: @g-makulik actually `List` is member of `System::Collections::Generic` namespace. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx

Comment: @user2367115 Glad you found it right ;-) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why they are down voting you since this IS actually C++. It's just microsoft's version. Also, you don't "NEED" stl vector or any "special" containers.. .Net already has a framework for some of these things. Usually mixing managed and native C++ is a bad idea but in some cases it works just fine.

Check out container such as the following:

```
List<int>^ list = gcnew List<int>;
list->Add(42);
array<String^>^ strarray = gcnew array<String^>(100);
strarray[0] = "Hello";
```

and so on..

Comment: The language is called C++/CLI, not to be confused with C++.

Comment: C++ and C++/CLI are distinct languages that target distinct platforms. The fact that a valid C++ program is also a valid C++/CLI program does not allow for the conclusion they are the same language. I downvoted the question because I cannot see the relation between the choice of a GUI framework and a container class.

Comment: Using this information I'm getting better answers from google :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use stl, Microsoft provides it for .net framework as STL/CLR since 3.5 version. ([see here for details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385954.aspx))

But .net framework contains own containers in System.Collections namespace (using boxing/unboxing operations to store values) for all versions ([see here for details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.aspx)) and System.Collections.Generic namespace (more using generics, without boxing/unboxing operations to store values) since version 2.0 ([see here for details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic.aspx)).
And if you want to show list items in controls (e.g ListBox or ComboBox), use BindingList< ([see here for details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx))

Merged answers!

Comment: Choose one of your answers.

Comment: Full my answer in both messages. Because of reputation it was devided on two parts.

Comment: Just delete one! Now it contains all of the links right? I'd guess there's a reason to restrict the number of links that can be posted by low rep SO members?!?

Comment: Yes, now here are all links and full answer, thanks for merge messages.